# Tengo una fecha yyyy.m Ej: 2016.1 en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una Base de datos con los periodos estilo yyyy.m así,

```
Periodo
2016.1 
2016.2
2016.3
.
.
.
2016.12
```

Por ejemplo:

```
fechas <- c('2016.1', '2016.2', '2016.3', '2016.12')
```

Pero no encuentro la manera de convertirla a una variable `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, tampoco tienes valores del tipo `Date`. Lo que tienes son períodos mensuales, posiblemente un dato de alguna serie de tiempo. Si necesitarás trabajar con los períodos, seguramente te convenga mucho más , manejar valores numéricos del tipo `201601, ..., 201612` que podrías generar fácilmente mediante:

```
fechas <- c('2016.1', '2016.2', '2016.3', '2016.12')
unlist(lapply(strsplit(fechas, '[.]'), FUN=function(x) {as.numeric(x[1])*100 + as.numeric(x[2])}))
[1] 201601 201602 201603 201612
```

Pero si realmente necesitas un valor de fecha, lo más sencillo es agregar a estos períodos el primer día, y la forma de procesarlo más sencilla, es usando el paquete `lubridate`:

```
library("lubridate")

fechas <- c('2016.1', '2016.2', '2016.3', '2016.12')
parse_date_time(fechas, "ym")
[1] "2016-01-01 UTC" "2016-02-01 UTC" "2016-03-01 UTC" "2016-12-01 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar el valor del día 1 de cada mes a tus fechas con `paste0` y usar `as.Date` para pasar los datos al formato de fecha.

```
fechas <- c('2016.1', '2016.2', '2016.3', '2016.12')
as.Date(paste0(fechas,".1"), format ="%Y.%m.%d")
```